# C# SelectListItem custom CSS

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, selectlistitem

```
Id    Value   IsActive
1      A       true
2      B       false
3      C       true
```

I'm currently working on a drop down list in MVC and I want to display my options with different font color based on the `IsActive` flag, example `true` will display in green, `false` will display in red.

```
ViewBag.listScore = new List<SelectListItem>();
ViewBag.listScore.AddRange(list.Select(l=> new SelectListItem() { 
    Text = l.Value  + (l.IsActive ? "" : "(Deactivated)"), 
    Value = l.Id.ToString() 
}));

@Html.DropDownList("score", new SelectList(listScore, "value", "text", 0));
```

What I currently does was insert an indicator on the `Text` temporary, after that I'll change the color and remove the indicator from the `Text` using `jquery` as below

```
$("#score option").each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('(Deactivated)') != -1) {
        $(this).css("color", "red");
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace('(Deactivated)', ''));
    }
})
```

This method will do what i expected, but I prefer do not using `jquery` to loop through every single option from the list, also not to enter the temporary indicator just to indicated what the option is.

Is there any improvement or another way to do this?

Any advice to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`@Html.DropDownList` is a HtmlHelper in razor. You can consider to make your own customized HtmlHelper class, or use HTML with razor syntax, e.g.

Consider Foo is your class, with `IsActive` and `Value` attribute

```
public class Foo 
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

In the Controller,

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{

    List<Foo> list = new List<Foo> 
    { 
        new Foo 
        {
            IsActive = true,
            Value = "A: I'm active"
        },

        new Foo 
        {
            IsActive = false,
            Value = "B: I'm deactivated"
        }, 
    };

    return View(list);
}
```

Finally, in the view, render the option's background color with respect to `IsActive` attribute,

```
@model List<Foo>

<html>
    <body>
        <select>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            { 
                <option style="background-color: @(item.IsActive ? "green" : "red")">@item.Value</option> 
            }
        </select>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't apply css selector by inner content text. But you could add class "disable" to appropriate options and add css like into this example

https://jsfiddle.net/56txqb70/

html

```
<select id="score">
<option value='1'>first</option>
<option value='2' class='disabled'>(Deactivated)</option>
</select>
```

css

```
#score option.disabled {
  color: red;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: the way you show me, only workable when we have code the drop down list by ourself in HTML, but using `mvc cshtml`, the drop down list generated using `@Html.DropDownList()`, which we do not have access to the html code to insert the css classes as our wishes

Comment: You could use Disabled property of SelectListItem instead. And css selector becomes to #score option[disabled]

Comment: sorry, I believe i miss out 1 point for my requirement, I need the option selectable even the `isActive` flag is false, else your suggestion will fit what I need

Comment: You could use Group property of SelectListItem  for that but it is the last one easy workaround

Comment: but the best way is using direct creation select with options from model  instead using @Html.DropDownList

Comment: i believe that the only way to do as using direct creation... thanks for the advise.